# Expand column with lists

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need your help about expanding column of lists with missing Expand button. I do not know what code to add in Advance editor and how to handle the problem. 
I have a dataset with a string column in a JSON format. When I loaded the dataset in PowerBI I parsed the string column to JSON and then started to expand all available columns. But one column doesnt have Expand button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oca4w.jpg)

What should I do?

```
let
    Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database(null),
    #"xero-245302" = Source{[Name="xero-245302"]}[Data],
    landlordhostifydatabase_Schema = #"xero-245302"{[Name="landlordhostifydatabase",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    api_data_apireservation_Table = landlordhostifydatabase_Schema{[Name="api_data_apireservation",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(api_data_apireservation_Table,{{"_sdc_batched_at", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Table.Buffer" = Table.Buffer(#"Sorted Rows"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Table.Buffer, {"api_id"}),
    #"Parsed JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"data", Json.Document}}),
    #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Parsed JSON", "data", {"id", "tags", "notes", "adults", "guests", "nights", "source", "status", "checkIn", "infants", "revenue", "added_by", "checkOut", "children", "currency", "guest_id", "subtotal", "base_price", "extra_info", "guest_name", "listing_id", "tax_amount", "updated_at", "guest_email", "guest_phone", "guest_photo", "net_revenue", "sum_refunds", "addons_price", "advance_days", "cancelled_at", "cleaning_fee", "confirmed_at", "extras_price", "payout_price", "cancel_policy", "custom_fields", "guest_details", "listing_photo", "listing_title", "owner_revenue", "price_details", "addons_details", "cancel_penalty", "cleaning_notes", "guest_location", "integration_id", "security_price", "service_charge", "extras_price_ex", "guest_languages", "planned_arrival", "price_per_night", "transaction_fee", "cancellation_fee", "extras_price_inc", "integration_name", "listing_nickname", "confirmation_code", "integration_photo", "parent_listing_id", "planned_departure", "channel_commission", "listing_channel_id", "beds_to_be_prepared", "integration_nickname", "channel_reservation_id"}, {"data.id", "data.tags", "data.notes", "data.adults", "data.guests", "data.nights", "data.source", "data.status", "data.checkIn", "data.infants", "data.revenue", "data.added_by", "data.checkOut", "data.children", "data.currency", "data.guest_id", "data.subtotal", "data.base_price", "data.extra_info", "data.guest_name", "data.listing_id", "data.tax_amount", "data.updated_at", "data.guest_email", "data.guest_phone", "data.guest_photo", "data.net_revenue", "data.sum_refunds", "data.addons_price", "data.advance_days", "data.cancelled_at", "data.cleaning_fee", "data.confirmed_at", "data.extras_price", "data.payout_price", "data.cancel_policy", "data.custom_fields", "data.guest_details", "data.listing_photo", "data.listing_title", "data.owner_revenue", "data.price_details", "data.addons_details", "data.cancel_penalty", "data.cleaning_notes", "data.guest_location", "data.integration_id", "data.security_price", "data.service_charge", "data.extras_price_ex", "data.guest_languages", "data.planned_arrival", "data.price_per_night", "data.transaction_fee", "data.cancellation_fee", "data.extras_price_inc", "data.integration_name", "data.listing_nickname", "data.confirmation_code", "data.integration_photo", "data.parent_listing_id", "data.planned_departure", "data.channel_commission", "data.listing_channel_id", "data.beds_to_be_prepared", "data.integration_nickname", "data.channel_reservation_id"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded data", {"data.tags", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

Comment: Please provide a test json file so we can have a look at it